# Roblox Lua Developpement

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to made a roblox game ,
but when I script in lua nothing happend when I touch the door :
The starter gui for text label

```
game.Workspace.text:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):Connect:(function())
    local text = script.Parent
    if game.Workspace.text.Value == 1 then
        script.Parent.Parent.Visible = true
        text.Text = "W"
        wait (.05)    
        text.Text = "We"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Wel"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Welc"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Welco"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Welcom"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Welcome"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Welcome !"
        wait (.05)
        wait (3)
        text.Text = "C"
        wait (.05)    
        text.Text = "Co"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Come"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Come I"
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Come In "
        wait (.05)   
        text.Text = "Come In !"
        wait (.05)   
        wait (3)
        script.Parent.Parent.Visible = false       
    end 
end)
```

The code of the door :

```
script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
    game.Workspace.text.Value = 1
    end
end)
```

Thanks for your answers , I never coded in lua

Comment: do you think it is a good idea to jump right into game developmetn with SDKs if you haven't programmed Lua yet? do a tutorial

Comment: I learned Lua since 2015 it's just I never used it

Comment: you cannot learn a language without using it. do some own debugging. put a print into your event callback, Think about why you call Connect here and connect there. count your parethesis.

Comment: Is there an error in the output when you try your code? What have you tried to do to fix your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are some problems here but I  am willing to help you! I'll show you how to properly animate text and efficiently!

First off you probably tried scripting the UI from a Server-Side script. When working with Graphical User Interface on Roblox, make sure you are coding Guis with a LocalScript so it is Client-Side. If you want to change UI for all Clients, you would use something called A RemoteEvent more on that later

I will provide the open source code and I will explain (if you want)

Here are some things you will need:

- A "RemoteEvent" inside of ReplicatedStorage (Name it: DoorEvent)
- A "ScreenGui" inside of StarterGui
- A TextLabel within the ScreenGui (customize to your liking)

Now, insert a regular script inside of ServerScriptService ("Just for exploit prevention)

Here is the door script:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local DoorEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("DoorEvent")
local door = workspace:FindFirstChild("NAME OF DOOR HERE")

door.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") ~= nil then
        local hum = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
        if hum then
            local player = game:GetService("Players"):FindFirstChild(hit.Parent.Name)
            if plr then
                DoorEvent:FireClient(plr)
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Basically this just uses a touched event to fire a RemoteEvent, we use it because of a Property called FilteringEnabled (exploiter purposes)

Now proceed to insert a LocalScript inside of the TextLabel and insert this code. (DONT WORRY IT MAY LOOK CONFUSING JUST ASK FOR CLARIFICATION IF YOU WANT)

Code:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local DoorEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("DoorEvent")
local TextLabel = script.Parent
local text

local function animateText(word)
    text = word
    for char = 1, #text do
        TextLabel.Text = string.sub(text,1,char)
        wait(.05)
    end
end

animateText("This is an example sentence, put whatever you want here as a string.")
wait(2.5)
animateText("You can repeat this as many times as you wish")

--If you want to get rid of the text when it's done you can either tween it or simply toggle the visibility)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect that one of your scripts might have a problem, check your Output pane. In this case it says:

```
19:02:05.822 - Players.x.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Frame.TextLabel.LocalScript:1: Expected '(', '{' or <string>, got ':'
```

This means that there is a colon where there shouldn't be one. The line needs to be:

```
game.Workspace.text:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):Connect(function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect statement on the game.Workspace.text:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):Connect:(function())

do this for that line instead :
game.Workspace.text:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Value"):Connect(function())